# Resolve must contain all promises even from controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Probably it's just as easy as I think it is, but I cannot really find an answer to my question on the internet, so I hope you guys know the answer just by looking at a small piece of my code.

Problem: I'm using the UI router in Angular and it loads the template before all the data is loaded. So all input fields receive the correct values AFTER the template is already loaded. So the input fields are empty for a second or two....

I think my resolve is not as it should be:

So my ui-router code looks something like this (check the resolve object):

```
$stateProvider.state('teststate', {
    url: '/test/',
    templateUrl: 'app/page/template.html',
    controller: 'testCtrl',
    resolve: {
        access: ["Access", function(Access) { return Access.isAuthenticated(); }],
        UserProfile: 'UserProfile'
    }
});
```

Now the controller contains the promise to get some data from an API url:

```
function TestCtrl($scope, $state, $stateParams, TestService) {

    TestService.get($stateParams.id).then(function(response) {
        $scope.data = response;
    });
}
```

Now the service (which connects to the API) should return the promise to the Controller:

```
TestService.factory('TestService', ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {

    var factory = {};

    factory.get = function(id) {
        return Restangular.one('api/test', id).get();
    }

    return factory;

}]);
```

Now, could the problem be, that because the `TestService.get()` (which connects to the API) within the Controller, gets executed NOT before the template is loaded, because it's not inside the `resolve` object? So the UI router doesn't resolve the call to the API? I'm just curious or I should move **all** methods which make API calls, to the resolve object of each stat inside the `$stateProvider`.

I could run a lot of tests, but if someone just directly knows the answer by just looking at this question, it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumptions are all correct.

If you resolve the `TestService.get` in routing config the data would be readily available to controller as an injectable resource

Comment: Thanks! Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your controller to run and your template to show before all your API calls are finished, you have to put all of them inside ui-routers `resolve`.

However, if API requests can take a little while it seems better UX to transition to the new page immediately and show some kind of loading indicator (e.g. [block-ui](http://angular-block-ui.nullest.com/#!/)) while your API call is running.

Comment: Another even simpler module is [angular-busy](https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy). just point it at a promise

Comment: block-ui you can also just enable it for all async requests. I guess the biggest difference between the two libs is that angular-busy is usually attached to specific part of the page, while block-ui blocks the whole page.

Comment: Can use it globally also